# Where are algebraic structures derivative from? Why are these sets with imposed operations and axioms given names?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

I'm trying to gain a general knowledge of set theory that spawned from a random question that happened to come up when I was thinking about mechanics:

**"Why do we use vectors for mechanics other than the fact that they represent reality accurately?"**

This led me to explore vector spaces, and then set theory for the first time, which is quite interesting. From what I've gathered, vector space is, in terms of algebraic structure, a module where the ring is instead a field. But even more basically, it's a set of objects called vector coordinates where a field operates on it yet its Cartesian product is still a member of the vector space. And even more basically, it's a set of objects with specific allowed operations due to underlying axioms (If this interpretation is wrong please don't hesitate to point that out). There's a confusion I've found with these and other algebraic structures describable using the former sentence, and I think my lack of experience with this branch of mathematics is to blame but I seek an answer nonetheless since I'm having trouble finding an answer online I like:

**Why do these structures exists? So what? Why can't I make a set, give it some allowed operations or interactions with some other algebraic structure like how vector spaces are defined and create my own structure? Why are these oddly specific structures important to us?**

I get that vector space is important to us because it, among other things, help us do Mechanics problems but how do we know it does theoretically? Or in other words, how do we know it does other than trying it and realizing it models reality accurately? It seems like some random creation of a set of objects with certain rules, and it conveniently can describe mechanics with such efficiency.

What gives? Why are these random structures so magically useful and not arbitrary clumps of axioms and objects? I realize that sounds a bit underhanded to describe such elegant mathematical abstractions, but I can't seem to explain how these things aren't such a description from my ignorance.

Comment: Who says you cannot pick a set and put some random algebraic structure? You can do that as much as you want — in all likelihood, we are not going to be interested in the result, though.

Comment: We do not know 'theoretically' that vector spaces help us do Mechanics: we know they do becuse they do. We are able to sent spaceships into outer space and have cars and we build bridges and computers and planes and mobile networks: vector spaces work *in practice*. There is no theoretical reason for that.

Comment: The algebraic structures that we study are studied because we observed them in practice. When groups were first dfined, groups had been in us for centuries. The definition of vector spaces captured an idea that had been around for ages: Euler did not know what a vector space is but he did know that the set of solutions of a linear differential equation of orden $n$ is a vector space of dimesion $n$ and so on. Our definitions of algbraic structures are not creations of new objects: they are decriptions of objecs that we already have.

Comment: Algebra happens when we notice that certain properties of things recur, and we abstract those properties and ask "what kinds of objects share those things which seem to be useful?" As an example of a property which both captures a common theme, and also catches the essential core of previous proofs which were diverse and complex, you might consider the Noetherian property, which reduced complex calculations in special cases across a range of situations to an essentially common understanding of finiteness.

Comment: @Mark Bennet So, in a set theory interpretation, we have almost  a "toolbox" of sorts, a tool to create sets of objects with certain properties and others objects to operate such sets. When we see something from nature with consistent, noticeable properties we use our toolbox to create a mathematical framework to describe these processes, and once it is consistent, use the framework to build upon this aspect of nature to find new insights?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Your answer is also very helpful. +1